# BURG broken by Windows

Tags: dual-boot, burg

I have successfully installed, using Super Boot Manager, BURG in a computer at my work.  After I boot into Windows XP, BURG is no longer operational.  The machine just boots to the BIOS screen, goes black, and then boots to the BIOS screen again *ad infinitum*.

The only way to recover I have found so far is to use a Boot-Repair USB, which restores either GRUB2 or MBR, not BURG.  Everything works fine under GRUB2, but I prefer the improved look of BURG to make things easier on my students.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

```
sudo burg-install --alt /dev/sda
```

I should have believed the directions from the website